# A tangent of the function $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: functions

A function $f(x) = x^3$ is given. What is the function of any tangent to $f(x)$?

Do I have to use derivation to solve this question? I have no clues.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent is $3t^2$ at any point $(t,t^3)$ by finding the derivative.

Now we need to make a line at this point, with slope $3t^2$.

We use the equation $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$

$$y-t^3 = 3t^2(x-t) \implies y - t^3 = 3t^2x - 3t^3 \implies 3t^2x -y - 2t^3 = 0$$

This is the equation of the tangent.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the value of $f'(x_0)$ is the slope of the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $x_0$. This means that the tangent to $f(x)$ at point $(x_0, f(x_0)$ will have the equation
$$y=kx+n$$
where $k=f'(x_0)$. Since you also know that the tangent goes through the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$, it should be easy to calculate $n$.